# Rendering Info Cards and modal box with forLoop only outs the last result in one of the fields

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, dom-manipulation

I am practising vainilla JS and DOM manipulation. I am rendering a group of cards populated with data from an Object (that I fetch from an API, but this happens also if i do it in local).
I get to render the cards,all good,  and create a button in each of them, that triggers a Modal box made with Bootstrap, with some additional information about that item.

The problem I have is that when I click on the button, the modal box only displays the information from the last element of the Object.

The function i wrote is as follows :

```
function createCards(data) {
    let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
    let modalTitle = document.getElementById('modalTitle');
    let modalBody= document.getElementById('modalBody');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        let divCard = document.createElement('div');
        divCard.setAttribute('class', 'card');

        let imgFish = document.createElement('img');
        imgFish.setAttribute('class', 'card-img-top');
        let imgUrl = data[i]['Species Illustration Photo'].src
        // console.log(imgUrl)
        imgFish.setAttribute('src', imgUrl);

        let divCardBody = document.createElement('div');
        divCardBody.setAttribute('class', 'card-body');

        let hCardTitle = document.createElement('h5')
        hCardTitle.innerHTML = data[i]['Species Name'];

        let pCardText = document.createElement('p');
        pCardText.setAttribute('class', 'card-text');
        pCardText.innerHTML = 'Kcal = ' + data[i].Calories

        let aInfoButton = document.createElement('a');
        aInfoButton.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
        aInfoButton.setAttribute('href', '#');
        aInfoButton.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
        aInfoButton.setAttribute('data-target', '#myModal');
        aInfoButton.innerHTML = 'Nutrional Info'

        cardContainer.appendChild(divCard);
        divCard.appendChild(imgFish);
        divCard.appendChild(divCardBody);
        divCardBody.appendChild(hCardTitle);
        divCardBody.appendChild(pCardText);
        divCardBody.appendChild(aInfoButton);

        //fill in Modal box 

        
        aInfoButton.onclick = function () {
            createModal(data);
            
        }

    }
    console.log("createCards() run")
}
```

and then, the function to populate the modal box :

```
function createModal(data) {

    let modalTitle = document.getElementById('modalTitle');
    let modalBody= document.getElementById('modalBody');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        modalTitle.innerHTML = data[i]['Species Name'];
        modalBody.innerHTML = data[i]['Cholesterol'];
    }
}
```

I tried also wrapping  the creation of those two innerHTML  from the modal box inside a different function, thinking it was a problem of time needed to render each item, but it seems that the problem is different, and I can't see which one.

Comment: I edited my commnent to try 2.) from @raderp answer
I added the event onclick to the button, and the function createModal() to populate the modal box

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, at the bottom of your for-loop, you are overwriting the innerHTML every time.

```
        modalTitle.innerHTML = data[i]['Species Name'];
        modalBody.innerHTML = data[i]['Cholesterol'];
```

So when you exit the for loop, what ever iteration of data is last is the one that will be in the modal.

2 ways to go about fixing:

1.) create a modal specific to each card.

2.) add an eventListener to the button that will populate the correct info onclick

Comment: That sounds like a good explanation :) 
I will try to implement (first I have to find out how) 2.) and see what happens 
Thanks!

Comment: I tried 2.) and added a
`aInfoButton.setAttribute('onclick', createModal(data))`

And created the function 
``` lang-js
function createModal(data) {

    let modalTitle = document.getElementById('modalTitle');
    let modalBody= document.getElementById('modalBody');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        modalTitle.innerHTML = data[i]['Species Name'];
        modalBody.innerHTML = data[i]['Cholesterol'];
    }
}
```

but i am getting the same behaviour ... I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I edited my original comment to include that